# Write a method that returns yes n% times

Tags: java, algorithm, percentage

We have a writePercent variable.We need a method that returns yes or no.

For example:

```
writePercent=30;

doWrite= doReadOrWrite(writePercent);

if(doWrite){

      //doWrite

}else{

      //do read

}
```

We need an implementation of doReadOrWrite() method which returns yes only 30% times, i.e. we get a 30% write and 70% read.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your hard work to write a program for achieving your goal

Comment: Tip #1: take a look on class named `Random`. Tip #2: in future avoid asking questions in form "I have a task. Any ideas?" Show what did you try to do and what real problem did you meet. Ask concrete question. Otherwise you will surprised to get downvotes and your questions will be probably closed.

Comment: Tried to keep a static variable, which out of every 10 calls to doReadOrWrite() method returns true for every Integer(writePercentage/100)th call. it'd work if we have a writePercentage of 10x i.e. 20,30,40 etc, but for a writePercent=24, it'll not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution could be to this:

```
boolean doReadOrWrite (int writePercent) {
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
  return randomInt <= writePercent;
}
```

so you'll have a *writePercent* probability of returning *true*

Answer (score 0):

Using java.util.Random, this should do the job:

```
boolean doReadOrWrite(int param) {

   Random rand = new Random();

   if (rand.nextInt(100) <= param) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```